# GCC Incremeting Macro

Tags: gcc, macros

i defined a macro like this

```
#define NoisyInc(x) (puts("incrementing"), (x)++)
int NINC;
NINC=NoisyInc(5);
printf("NoisyInc is %d\n",NINC);
```

But while building the program am getting this error

```
C:\Users\DTS\Desktop\macros.c|36|error: lvalue required as increment operand|
```

What will be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as your error says, the line:

`NINC=NoisyInc(5);`

during preprocessing will be turned into:

`(puts("incrementing"), (5)++)`

`5++`: you cannot post-increment literals.

Comment: What will be the best way to do that in a macro?

Comment: It depends on what you'd like to do - but I'd guess you'd rather do this:
`int NINC=5; NoisyInc(NINC);`